# Use variable in where clause PL/SQL

Tags: variables, plsql, dbms-output

I have several queries unioned together, all of which have the same date parameter in the where clause. I'd like to make this easy to update. I've written T-SQL variables but PL SQL is a bit different. Trying to figure out how to execute something like this:

```
DECLARE
l_DATE DATE:= '01-JAN-18';
BEGIN
SELECT
ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE
FROM
T.ORDERS
WHERE
ORDER_DATE >= DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_DATE);
END;
```

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer  Version 17.2.0.188
Oracle Database 11g  11.2.0.40.0

Comment: In Oracle the syntax for date literals is [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Answer (score 0):

You should refer variable directly:

```
DECLARE
l_DATE DATE:= '01-JAN-18';
BEGIN
  SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE
  -- BULK COLLECT INTO collection
  -- Oracle does not return directly from stored procedure like SQL Server
  FROM T.ORDERS
  WHERE ORDER_DATE >= l_DATE;
END;
```

---

Oracle 12c:

```
DECLARE
   l_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_DATE DATE:= '01-JAN-18';
BEGIN

  OPEN l_cur FOR
  SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE
  FROM T.ORDERS
  WHERE ORDER_DATE >= l_DATE;

  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(l_cur);
END;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=434dd130393708a3ea813c8959878432)**

Comment: ORA-06550: line 22, column 10:
PLS-00302: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared

Comment: @KatieGray Oracle 12c and newer